# как работает в oracle: count(1) over (partition by * order by*)

Tags: sql, oracle

подскажите, почему запрос так странно отрабатывает?

```
with a as (
select 1 as id, 'a' as type from dual
union
select 2 as id, 'a' as type from dual
union
select 3 as id, 'b' as type from dual
union
select 4 as id, 'b' as type from dual
union
select 5 as id, 'b' as type from dual
)

select type, count(1) over (partition by type order by id) from a;
```

Получил:

```
a | 1
a | 2
b | 1
b | 2
b | 3
```

Ожидал:

```
a | 2
a | 2
b | 3
b | 3
b | 3
```

Я думал что кол-во должно считаться по всей группе, а не по строчно. Почему считает построчно?

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык. А вообще, когда в over() указан order by количество должно считаться кумулятивно по строкам, что собственно и наблюдается. Вот если order by не был бы задан то результат был бы такой как вы предположили, было бы итоговое количество по группе у каждой записи

Comment: Спасибо Mike,
кумулятивно - да, но почему?
почему он не оценивает всю группу (count(), max()), а работает по-строчно?

Comment: Потому что так и задумано. Какое бы другое назначение вы придумали бы в данном случае для `order by` ведь если выводить одно и то же значение (суммарное) то нет разницы в каком порядке это делать. внимательно прочитайте  пункт касающийся `order by` в предложении `over()` в документации https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конструкции аналитической функции указано order by id. Если под группой Вы понимаете TYP, то замените ID на TYP или удалите вовсе.

```
select type, count(1) over (partition by type ) from a
```

[image: Результат выполнения запроса]

Это особенности аналитической функции.